# Objective-C, programmatically detect i386, or x86_x64 architecture of binary?

Tags: objective-c, binary, x86-64

Is there a way to programmatically detect/determine if a binary (separate from my application) has been compiled i386, x86_x64, or both? I imagine there is a way (obviously), although I really have no idea how. Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: I found an example on the Apple developer website, although it's written in C and setup to be used more as a command line tool. If anyone would know how to implement it into my objective-c code that would be extremely helpful.

- Example [C] code: [CheckExecutableArchitecture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CheckExecutableArchitecture/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: You can parse the output of `file` or `objdump`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to know if current architecture is i386 or x86_64 in macs? (Xcode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297842/how-to-know-if-current-architecture-is-i386-or-x86-64-in-macs-xcode)

Comment: @grahamparks, that appears to only detect what the architecture the application itself (with that code) is running. I'm trying to detect that of a completely different binary unrelated to my application.

Comment: I found some C code from the apple developer samples, although I'm not sure how to integrate it with my objective-c code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)checkArchitecture {

NSArray *bundleArch = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/path/to/other/bundle"] executableArchitectures];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `mach-o` headers and simply load the binary and then check the `mach_header`. You should read the Mach-O format description from Apple for more info, it includes everything you need: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html

Comment: @JustSide, How would I include them? i.e. `-(void)detect { [self architecture]; }`?